# IBM jdk 1.4 keytool command to create valid public and private key for BKS provider

Tags: bouncycastle, keytool, ibm-jdk

I am trying to create the certificate on IBM JDK1.4 using bouncy castle as a provider, I am using this command to create the certs, with this commands private key is created , but I am not able to create public key for it.

Also I am looking for the information on hat is valid keystore and keystore providers for the BC can I use IBMJCE for bouncy castle

> keytool -genkey -alias alias -keystore Maritz_sso_keys.bks -storepass password -storetype BKS -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -sigalg SHA256withRSA -keyalg RSA